# When is three of a kind a valid set in Indian Rummy?

Tags: rummy, indian-rummy

Is the following a valid `set` in Indian-Rummy when we're using three decks of cards? What about when we use two decks?

6♠️ - 6♠️ - joker

Comment: Welcome to the Boardgames.SE, be sure to read through our help pages to get an idea of what this site is all about.  https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: @NeilMeyer FYI you can write `[tour]` to get a magic short link to our [tour] :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That set is acceptable only in Indian Rummy's three deck variant. (I'll call Indian Rummy by its name Paplu here for some better clarity.)

Two-deck Paplu and regular Rummy only has sets (same card value, different suites) and runs (same suit, sequential card values) and that move isn't legal in this format.

Three-deck Paplu allows the set type you describe, called a tanala:

> When three decks are used it is customary also to allow an additional type of combination consisting of three identical cards - such as ♣️10-♣️10-♣️10. This is known as a tanala, and is treated as equivalent to a straight run.
>
> — [Pagat's definition of Indian Rummy](https://www.pagat.com/rummy/indian.html)

The joker is a wild card that can stand in for any other card at all, which means it's legitimate for completing the tanala.